# How to integrate Paypal using React Native expo?

Tags: react-native, paypal, expo

I am unable to integrate Paypal using React Native expo. It can be possible using WebView, but I don't want to use WebView.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Seams like your out of luck ([Source](https://forums.expo.io/t/integrate-paypal-with-react-native-application/18255) ), however there is a topic on the roadmap you can upvote ( [link](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/paypal-api) )

Another solution that might work if you are willig to make the payment with paypal through google you could implement in app purchases  (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/) they support paypal purchases ( [source](https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-billing) )

im not sure if this works for IOS

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this library would be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-expo-paypal-integration. If not you can eject from the expo and use react-native-paypal

Or please upvote for the feature to be implemented in Expo:

- https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/paypal-api
- https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-user-to-user-payments-without-detaching
- https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-for-payments