# How to implement PayPal in Expo ReactNative app using Webview without Nodejs

Tags: react-native, paypal, expo, react-native-webview

I am developing an Ecpo ReactNative app and i looking to integrate PayPal to allow users to purchase some products using Webview, but I don't know how to do it. I came across this article: https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/integrating-paypal-in-your-react-native-app-4dcf89e11dd which explains how to do it but he uses a nodejs server and i won't necessarily implement a Nodejs server...

I also came across this article: [How to integrate Paypal using React Native expo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602205/how-to-integrate-paypal-using-react-native-expo) where they offer other solutions, but which didn't satisfy me.

Comment: Why didn't the other solutions satisfy?

Comment: because he is looking for an integration solution without Webview. I am looking with Webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use [a server integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls) (nodejs or otherwise), then obviously only client-side JS will be available. Here is a demo pattern of what you can do: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

There's nothing React-specific about it.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to integrate it yet but I'm doing it as soon as possible

Comment: Hi, I tried to integrate your solution via a Webview but unfortunately, the Webview does not support the import of files. see [non-working method](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#loading-local-html-files). Currently, I am looking for another solution

Comment: @Neosoulink Hi, did you managed to use PayPal on an Expo App? I am struggling a lot with this and I don't want to eject the project.

Comment: Hi @HernánCasillas, I used a local server to provide me an HTML page that mange my paypal api